# Transient RSS feeds in wp_options not removed automatically?

Tags: database, cron, options

I just noticed 55.000 entries(!) in my wp_options table. I had not been there for a while.

So I ran:

```
delete from `wp_options` where `option_name` like '_transient_timeout_rss%'
delete from `wp_options` where `option_name` like '_transient_rss_%'
```

And... it is now back to 645 entries...

How can I have these older RSS entries removed automatically since transient seems to be eternal.

Could It be that on my webhost cron is not working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep, this does seem like a cron issue.

[Core Control](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/core-control/) plugin is good to diagnose cron tasks (among other things).

I am still unsure what is the reason of you getting overrun with feed transients. However I had written some [code that might help with automatic cleanup](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6602/are-transients-garbage-collected/6652#6652).

Comment: I tried scheduling a post and well... it was actually posted grmbl so it looks like cron works but the rss feeds are never ever removed. maybe I can cron the 2 sql lines to run once every week *GRIN*

Comment: @edelwater should work... it places its page in `Tools`

Comment: but uhm... its not part of wp_scheduled_delete ?

Comment: Actually I am no longer sure it is linked to cron... Transients are deleted if they are outdated on access and class that handles feed transients has `unlink()` method as well...

Answer (score 3):

The entries life for different time. You can run a sql for delete all:
`DELETE FROM`wp_options`WHERE`option_name`LIKE ('_transient%_feed_%')`

THe easiest wy for run a sql direct on the database is the plugin [Adminer](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/adminer/) inside the WP Backend. More you can read on [this post](http://wpengineer.com/2114/delete-all-feed-cache-via-sql-in-wordpress/) about delete the transient-cache of feeds.