# Are transients garbage collected?

Tags: options, transient

This question got me thinking [Transient RSS feeds in wp_options not removed automatically?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5704/transient-rss-feeds-in-wp-options-not-removed-automatically)

Transients are supposed to expire and be deleted. However the only way I see this handled is when transient is expired and requested, then it is deleted during request.

What if transient is expired but never requested after that? From description in Codex I thought that some kind of garbage collection is implied. Now I am not so sure and can't find any code that performs such.

So will it just be stuck in database forever?

Comment: theoretically they should be removed when cron is run (if they are expired)

Comment: @Ambitious Amoeba I do not see anything with that functionality hooked to cron. That is why I am asking - it seems to be an assumption I am not sure is valid.

Comment: It's my understanding that transients are not really real cron processes, they at least require someone to request a page in order for them to be created/removed(but it's the next best thing to a real cron process). I've not monitored my transients, are you seeing transients hang around often after expiry?

Comment: @t31os yes I do see them hanging, but I have no information on how long they can hang before it can be said definitively that they are not garbage collected

Comment: @Rarst - I'm not sure how cleanup is determined either, are you seeing this problem with any particular transients or differing ones?

Comment: @t31os I am not going to waste time on coding transients logging contraption before I know if they are supposed to be garbage collected at all. :)

Comment: @Rarst - Beats me mate, just wanted to share a few thoughts.. :)

Comment: it seems that expired transients are deleted when `get_transient` fires off - http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.0.4/wp-includes/functions.php#L721

Comment: So you shouldn't see any expired transients in the db, unless something went wrong with delete_option()

Comment: @Ambitious Amoeba yeah, I kinda mentioned that in question. My point is - transient being created doesn't assume or guarantee that it is ever going to be requested. Stressing the original question - **when and if expired transient gets deleted if I never _get_ it?**

Comment: but what's the point of using transients then?

Comment: @Ambitious Amoeba the point is that transients are caching mechanism. Cache concept assumes expiring data and doesn't assume guaranteed hits. If cache doesn't cleanup expired data then it is leaking resources.

Comment: it asssumes you clean up the expired data, but yes, you're right, there are situations in which it would never get deleted. Like removing a widget which uses transients. You should submit a ticket on the trac for this :)

Comment: @Rarst - Sounds like a perfect thing to write a patch for and submit to trac?

Comment: @MikeSchinkel yeaaaah... after someone answers definitively at last if damn transients are (or are supposed to be supposed to be) garbage collected :)

Comment: @Rarst - The only way to tell for sure it to trace through the code...

Comment: They don't need to be "garbage collected". If you never fetch them, then it doesn't matter if they're there or not.

Comment: @Otto if you start to have **tens of thousands** of such garbage entries in options table (which can and does happen in practice, see linked question) I think it quite matters, no?

Comment: No, it really doesn't. Databases can have millions and millions of rows in them without appreciable slowdown. It's called "indexing", and it stays fast as heck even with lots and lots of rows: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_(database).

What's more, calling the SQL DELETE on them doesn't actually delete them from the database. It just removes them from the index, until you do an OPTIMIZE TABLE on the table as well, which is a long running operation. There is generally no need to "clean up" records in a database. Let the database do its job. It's better at it than you are.

Comment: To be more specific about it, you may notice that transients in the database have their autoload flag set to "no" which means they don't get loaded on startup. The primary slowdown from any database query is the actual data transfer from the database to the program. Queries themselves, if written correctly and properly indexed (meaning the query doesn't cause a table scan), take virtually no time by comparison. Doesn't matter if you have 100 records or 100,000, as doing a simple SELECT on an indexed field is an O(log(n)) operation. This doesn't really change until you get 1M+ records or so.

Comment: @Otto Could you please move this to an answer so information is more visible? I do not argue that it will take a lot of garbage entries to screw things up... But if anything is leaking resources (which easily happen with transients because they have key length limit that is not checked, easy to generate crapload of them and never touch again because key is broken) then sooner or later it will screw things up. I am not screaming "fix this in core", but I don't see cleanup as useless either.

Comment: "Screw things up" is a bit of a vague statement. The most that I can see happening is that the database gets too large for a limited account space. It's not going to actually break anything until it gets very, very large indeed. I work with tables that have 20 million records in them. Searching them is a bit slow, but not unreasonably so. You're correct about the key length limit, but 45 chars is plenty for every realistic case I can think of. Okay, sure, it's possible to do something crazy, but does that happen often? Seems like plugin author should be notified instead of a workaround...

Comment: @Otto "not often" and "never" are different things. If I get to making plugin out of this I plan to add warning for key length as well. However I do not see a point in keeping garbage data in database just because transient work that way. It may not be a bug, but it is hardly a feature.

Comment: My point isn't to keep them in the database just because they work that way. My point is that trying to "garbage collect" them costs more than it saves, in virtually all cases. It's actually counterproductive.

Comment: Related trac ticket: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/20316

Answer (score 53, accepted):

### They now are

Starting with WordPress 3.7 expired transients are deleted on database upgrades, see [#20316](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/20316)

---

### Old answer

If someone can't show me otherwise it seems that transients are not garbage collected after all. What makes it worse is that unlike options they are not guaranteed to be stored in database. So there is no reliable way to fetch list of all transients to check them for expiration.

Some makeshift code to do garbage collection if database is used for storage:

```
add_action( 'wp_scheduled_delete', 'delete_expired_db_transients' );

function delete_expired_db_transients() {

    global $wpdb, $_wp_using_ext_object_cache;

    if( $_wp_using_ext_object_cache )
        return;

    $time = isset ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'] ) ? (int)$_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'] : time() ;
    $expired = $wpdb->get_col( "SELECT option_name FROM {$wpdb->options} WHERE option_name LIKE '_transient_timeout%' AND option_value < {$time};" );

    foreach( $expired as $transient ) {

        $key = str_replace('_transient_timeout_', '', $transient);
        delete_transient($key);
    }
}
```

Comment: $time = $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']; and then making use of $time in the SQL query - don't do that. Deal more carefully with $_SERVER variables / values to prevent SQL injections.

Comment: @hakre hm... I picked that from presentation on PHP performance that recommended it over using `time()` which can cause bugs (execution is not instant by nature). Request time is being set by PHP itself, doesn't come from any kind of user-supplied data. Why is this vulnerability?

Comment: @Rarst: I didn't say that you should not use it, you should just ensure that it is safely encoded to be used inside the SQL query. You should do this with every variable from an external source. $_SERVER variables might not be set as expected, and instead, set by the requesting user even. I only wanted to propagate some good coding practice. As always, to learn about the real state of availability, see the docs. For PHP 4 for example, such a variable does not exists and might be overwritten by a custom header or environment variable - http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: @hakre fixed (I think), thanks for PHP4 reminder btw (I can't wait for WordPress to drop support of it)

Comment: That looks much better in my eyes ;). Let's hope that there is no problem with time() and negative integers that might delete all or no transients than by accident. Never trust a running system :P

Comment: In case you weren't aware, _ is a single char wildcard for LIKE statements, and should ideally be escaped. :)

Comment: @Denis yeah, I know that... But no practical difference in this query?.. Unless someone manages to name option XtransientXtimeoutX or something.

Comment: Wouldn't you use $wpdb->prepare() in order to properly protect yourself from tainted data such as what @hakre was talking about? This would also solve the escaping of the '_' as well. I'd recommend using it, as a best practice.

Comment: @Tom other than "to be really really sure" this specific query doesn't really need prepare and I didn't bother to add it.

Comment: You're right now that I look at it. The (int) probably is all the protection you need on that server variable.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `_transient_timeout_%`? Just to make sure it really is what WP uses as prefix? ;)

Answer (score 21):

Moving some of the comments from the discussion into an answer, with re-wording and re-formatting..

Basically, what it comes down to is that unless you have a super extreme case, they don't really need to be "garbage collected". If you never fetch them, then it doesn't matter if they're there or not.

See, transients are stored in the options table by default. In a base install, the options table will have maybe 100 entries in it. Each transient adds two more entries, but even if you have thousands, they don't affect the site speed, since they're not autoloaded.

On startup, WordPress loads the options into memory, but it only loads options that have their autoload flag turned on. Transients don't get this, and so don't get loaded into memory. Only transients that get actually used later will incur a cost.

From the database's perspective, the options table has indexes on both the option Id and the option name. Transients are always loaded based on the name (key), and so the lookups for them are always simple selects on a single unique key value. Thus the lookup is O(log(n)) and is super fast. With a Big-O of log(n), you'd have to get into the millions and millions of rows before it became noticable. Frankly, the overhead in the setup and teardown of the query, along with the actual data transfer, is way longer. The query itself runs in essentially zero-time by comparison. So simply *having* extra unused rows doesn't affect anything but using extra disk space.

Indexing in databases is one of those deep-read kind of ideas that doesn't make sense to people who haven't actually understood what's going on behind the scenes. Databases are designed for fast data retrieval, from the ground up, and can handle this sort of thing without issues. This is a pretty good read: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_(database)

Now, cleanup in the most obvious way (calling SQL DELETE on them) doesn't actually delete them from the database. It just removes them from the index and marks the row as "deleted". Again, this is just how databases work. To actually clear up the disk space, you have to then continue on and do an OPTIMIZE TABLE afterwards, and this is not a fast operation. It takes time. Probably more time than it's worth. It's probably not enough to give you a savings in CPU time, in total.

If you have some case that is causing a continual insertion of new transients that are not being used, then you need to find the underlying problem instead. What is inserting these transients? Are they using a changing or mutating key? If so, then the plugin or code causing this should be fixed to, basically, not do that. That will be more helpful, because it's likely that the code that isn't creating them properly also isn't retrieving them, and thus doing more work than it has to do.

On the other hand, there may be a case where transients are being created for something like every post. This may indeed be perfectly acceptable. I do this myself in SFC, to store incoming comments from Facebook. Each post has a potential transient associated with it, which means two extra rows per post. If you have 10k posts, you'll have 20k rows in the options table (eventually). This isn't bad or slow, because again, there's very little difference between 100 rows and 20,000 rows as far as databases really care. It's all indexed. It's fast as heck. Sub-sub-milliseconds.

When you start getting into *millions* of rows, then I'd be worried. When the options table size increases above hundreds of megabytes, then I'd be concerned enough to take a closer look. But generally speaking, this isn't an issue except for extreme cases. It's certainly not an issue for anything smaller than something like a large news site, with hundreds of thousands of posts. And for any site large enough for it to be a problem, you should be using an external object cache of some sort, and in *that* case, the transients get automagically stored there instead of in the database.

Comment: NB: transients with no expiration **do** get autloaded, and no expiration is the **default**, so where an application / plugin is creating lots of transients and not setting an expiration they will be using chunks of memory on every page/post load.

Comment: There is no reason to use a "transient with no expiration", because that is basically identical to a normal "option".

Comment: Sure, but [it's the default](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/set_transient). As such, many plugin authors are adding non-expiring transients.

Comment: Also, not identical to an option, as it will be purged when using an object cache -- see [recent article on WPEngine](http://wpengine.com/2013/02/wordpress-transient-api/) for details.

Comment: Well, the solution here is simple: Don't use those plugins. They're doing it wrong. Transients are not to be used as sessions, you should not use them without a meaningful expiration, and they should not have mutating or changing keys.

Comment: :) (because it's not because the WordPress default is wrong, eh?)

Comment: That depends. What would you consider a sensible default value there instead?

Comment: Say, 7 days. If a plugin / theme author wants something bigger or smaller, they'll specify it. If they want autoload, they shouldn't have to specify 0 for expiration (= infinity), but that's what they've currently got with the expiration parameter doing double duty as the yes/no autoload parameter. Either way, default expiration shouldn't also lead to autoload=yes as default; that's just asking for trouble.

Comment: In my considered opinion, not specifying an expiration should throw a fatal error and break the site. But then I'm not in charge. A transient with no expiration is stupid and meaningless. If you want to use the object cache, then just use the object cache directly with the wp_cache functions. That said, there are tickets to have future version of WordPress clean up old transients, mainly because it's "unsightly" more than anything else.

Answer (score 20):

Otto - I couldn't disagree with you more.
The issue is that eventually with all those transients, the size of the table becomes ridiculous. It doesn't take millions of rows to bog down. I'm currently dealing with an options table that has over 130k rows, and hangs regularly. Because the value field is a large text type, even looking for only the "autoload" rows becomes a nightmare of performance. Those value fields are stored separately from the rest of the row data. 
Even though it's logically part of the same table, joins must happen in order to pull up the rows you want. Joins that now take forever because the data you need is spread all over the place on disk. Profiling (using jet profiler for mysql) has proven this.

Adding auto-load to the clustered key might help solve this problem. Clustering on Autoload Desc, ID ASC for example, would allow all the autoload rows to bunch together first on disk. Even still I think you're looking at a huge strain from a DB perspective.

Personally I think the design of this system is wack. The options table seems to have turned into a general catch-all for a lot of things. That's fine if the value field is small enough to be included on the same page as the rest of the rowdata, and can be indexed effectively. Unfortunately that's not the case. Whoever designed this needs to go back to DB101 class.

Comment: true, but consider that when WordPress development started, nobody thought that it would reach to have thousands of plugins using options table as their data storage :)

Comment: @onetrickpony that's why it's important to always take your time and do things right, whether you expect it to be huge someday or not :)