# WordPress Plugin: Where should I put my cookies for cURL?

Tags: plugins, cookies, curl

Currently creating a plugin with cURL and I need a place that will work for most WordPress servers (Unix or Windows) to store my cookie file. Anyone have a suggestion or best practices? I've been googling for a while now and I think I found something about wp_temp_dir, but googling that keyword gives me only a thousand and one results about solving some install error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transients seem to be appropriate storage. Just note that if you will generate a lot of this and they will be disposable then you [will need to cleanup old transients](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6602/are-transients-garbage-collected).

As for your cURL/filename issue - it is bad practice to use cURL directly in WordPress. WP provides [HTTP API](http://codex.wordpress.org/HTTP_API) that abstracts remote requests.

Unfortunately it is bit poorly documented. As far as I understand you pass cookies in arguments array with `cookies` key to its functions.

Comment: Got everything to work and recoded everything to use the WordPress HTTP API. This page really helped by the way, http://planetozh.com/blog/2009/08/how-to-make-http-requests-with-wordpress/ It's a little dated but the info still applies to the new HTTP API on the codex.

Answer (score 0):

You could store cookies in [transients](http://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API). That way, its absctracted enough from the actual storage location that it should work across environments. Transients are stored in the wp_options table of the database by default, but can be memcached by plugins.

Comment: I don't know if this works : ( the php cURL code requires that a filename be passed in. `curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $this->getCookieFile());`

Comment: How do I move this question by the way? Or do I just have to repost it?