# Should I remove transients from the wp_options table?

Tags: database, optimization, options

I have been doing some cleaning up in the database of one of my WordPress installs, and I noticed that the `wp_options` table was about 2.1mb, and had 1200 rows.  I've gotten it down to around 800 rows, and 1.2mb.  However, there are a bunch of transients.

Should I remove these?  I know they don't autoload, so it probably isn't causing strain on the database.

Most of the transients have formatting like the following:

```
_site_transient_browser_03df11ec4fda7630a5...
_site_transient_browser_065e09a1287aadfb4d...
_site_transient_timeout_browser_03df11ec4f...
_site_transient_timeout_browser_065e09a128...
_transient_feed_1a5f760f2e2b48827d4974a608...
_transient_feed_f8e8c12cc5c787789728d7481a...
_transient_feed_mod_e6460a14e5784b3ee64f91...
_transient_timeout_feed_1a5f760f2e2b48827d...
```

So, is it worth taking the time to remove these?

Thanks for reading!  Any thoughts are appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not an amount that is likely to cause performance issues. However if you are concerned about leftover transients it is worth looking into if any code you are using is consistently "leaking" them (creating transients that are never removed).

See [Are transients garbage collected?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/6602/847) for relevant discussion and some code snippets.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! That thread looks extremely informative as well.  Is there any harm in removing the transients?

Comment: @Ryan in plain removing them - no, although there might be no effect either because as Otto notes in his answer on that question you need to run optimize to actually get table reshuffled after removal. As per my answer - it's more important to pro-actively not have them spawned in large quantities than remove them reactively.

Comment: Thanks again!  I will see if I can find what's causing these, but there isn't an overwhelming amount.  I read other people having 100,000's of transients in the wp_options, and while that seems like a more serious problem, having a couple hundred rows of transients doesn't seem like anything to overanalyze... Which is exactly what I'm doing, haha.