# How to delete transients written by fetch_feed()?

Tags: transient, feed

I'm using fetch_feed() to cache external rss sources displayed in a widget. in case the widget (or, more likely, the whole plugin) is deleted/deactivated, i want to manually delete all related transients.

In [class-feed.php](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/class-feed.php#L23) $filename is passed to the constructor of WP_Feed_Cache_Transient{}, which obviously handles the transients for fetch_feed. I just havent figured out how the variable is generated to store it with the widgets for later delete actions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This data should be automatically deleted after **12 hours**, that's the default feed cache TTL.

So this kind of house cleaning, for data added by the [WordPress transients API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API), might be unnecessary.

But let's check out what kind of data is stored.

If you take for example the feed for your current question:

```
http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/feeds/question/172444
```

and fetch it with:

```
$feed = fetch_feed( 'http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/feeds/question/172444' );
```

then you would get 4 rows in the `wp_options` table:

1. `_transient_feed_mod_89d724e05be3479dcbee0fd481470c97`
2. `_transient_timeout_feed_mod_89d724e05be3479dcbee0fd481470c97`
3. `_transient_feed_89d724e05be3479dcbee0fd481470c97`
4. `_transient_timeout_feed_89d724e05be3479dcbee0fd481`

The `_transient_timeout_*` rows are automatically added by WordPress to know when to delete the transients.

Notice that:

```
echo $md5_of_feed_url = md5( 'http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/feeds/question/172444' );
```

is

```
89d724e05be3479dcbee0fd481470c97
```

So you would need to know the *md5 of the feed url*, to remove this data with the [`delete_transient()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/delete_transient) function:

```
delete_transient( 'feed_'     . $md5_of_feed_url ); 
delete_transient( 'feed_mod_' . $md5_of_feed_url );
```

Comment: Thanks @birgire for explaining it in detail. I learn more here everyday than any other place. :)

Comment: Thanks @Roberthue, you're welcome. I'm also learning lots of great stuff from this site everyday, this is a great place for WordPress devs ;-)

Comment: thanks @birgire – exactly the answer i was looking for! one more question: does _transient_feed_mod_* contain the timestamp the feed was fetched?

Comment: great. yes, it contains the value of `time()`, i.e. the Unix timestamp. I updated the answer with the corresponding delete functions.

Comment: as i see now, in case you pass an array to fetch_feed(), for each element (preferably containing an url) these four transients are generated separately.

Comment: yes, they are separated for each feed url.

Comment: FYI, if you're using memcached, you'll need to instead do: `wp_cache_delete( 'feed_'     . $md5_of_feed_url, 'transient' );` and `wp_cache_delete( 'feed_mod_' . $md5_of_feed_url, 'transient' );`

Comment: Thanks for the comment @James - `delete_transient()` already has an internal  `wp_using_ext_object_cache()` check and uses `wp_cache_delete( ... )` for external object cache. Wouldn't that cover it?

Comment: Ahh yep, I guess so :)

Comment: To remove all of them, you can use a function like this one: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/130378/97843