# what effective ways are there to debug cron

Tags: wp-cron

Right now about 25% of the entries in my access log (which do not show resource like css, images, etc) are requests to wp-cron.php. I assume there is some process event that got "stuck" and keep firing but how can I find which one?

It is a live server there the amount of hacking I can do at the code to find the problem is limited.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a simple plugin that spits the data out into a private admin page, you basically want to use:

```
$cron = _get_cron_array();
$schedules = wp_get_schedules();
$tranny = get_transient('doing_cron');
//var_dump or loop over these
```

There are several plugins that do this that style the output to make it easier to read and organize, also make sure you don't have anything manually hitting the `wp-cron.php` (like a server side script).

Also read this: [Are transients garbage collected?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6602/are-transients-garbage-collected)

Answer (score 0):

A pretty elegant way to go with this is to install [Debug bar](https://wordpress.org/plugins/debug-bar/) plugin, which is a great tool for developers + it's addon [Debug bar cron](https://wordpress.org/plugins/debug-bar-cron/).

Answer (score 0):

While @Wyck's and @vlood's answers are good for many scenarios, I ended up with another way to isolate where the problem might be by just directly surfing to example.com/wp-cron.php which in my case triggered properly all events which means that the problem is most likely with the wp cron lock mechanism which uses the `doing_cron` transient.

Comment: This is why in some situations you disable WP cron and just manually hit that url with a server side script.

Comment: @wyck, yeh not sure if I should spend time on debugging (nothing too critical done by cron right now) or just set a real cron to activate it. should probably post another question about how that transient is supposed to work at all.