# How to flush feed? Or set timeout on feed so that it isn't cached?

Tags: rss, feed

I'm trying to add a custom feed format to my site (basically exporting data to an Excel file) and I'm getting confused by the feed caching settings. I can't figure out how to flush the cached feeds, or to turn off feed caching altogether while I'm in development.

I've tried deleting all the `_transient_feed...`, `_transient_timeout_feed...` and `_transient_rss...` options, but I'm still seeing the cached feeds.

And, based on some advice in [this support forum thread](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-can-i-flush-the-rss-cache), I tried on a whim adding this line to my wp-config.php:

```
define('MAGPIE_CACHE_AGE', 0);
```

(Obviously I'd like some caching of feeds, but it would help in development to be able to turn off the feed caching.)

Anybody got any suggestions?

---

**Some clarification:**

Sorry, I think I wasn't clear enough in the initial question, and then I threw you all by referring to the magpie cache, which was completely on the wrong path. I was shooting blind at first.

I'm adding a feed to my site using `add_feed()`. The function that generates the feed is using the [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) class to write an excel spreadsheet. Then I'm setting appropriate headers for download, and outputting the .xls file data.

I think my problem might actually be a browser caching issue. The urls that I'm trying to output my feeds from look this this: **mysite.com/facility/ummc/?feed=master_log** and the xls file that's generated is called Master_Log.xls.

Adding a cache busting string to the url request can get around the cache, i.e. requesting a feed from **mysite.com/facility/ummc/?feed=master_log&now=12ag4oSduq344** ... I was just wondering if there was any way of disabling the cache altogether.

Comment: How do you add the custom feed?

Comment: is this of any help: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5704/transient-rss-feeds-in-wp-options-not-removed-automatically ?

Comment: do you have  WP_DEBUG on?

Comment: Are you talking about feed you are generating like `domain.com/feed/something/` or feed you are retrieving with `fetch_feed()` ?

Comment: Clarified. Its a feed that I'm generating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It definitely might be a caching issue. I find [REDbot](http://redbot.org/) is excellent for quick check of how result is served and what are its caching settings.

Comment: Thanks for the link - that was very helpful. Found out - as I was starting to suspect - it wasn't a WordPress issue at all. Tweaking the headers I was outputting with my .xls file solved the problem.

Answer (score 4):

If you ever need to just update a single feed RIGHT NOW, for example, to reflect changes made in site settings or a plugin, all you have to do is **update any of the posts that appear in the feed.**

The reason for this is that WordPress, I conjecture, when serving up a feed, checks all the posts in the feed, and if none of them have been updated since the feed was cached, it serves the cache, but if a post has been updated, it regenerates the feed and refreshes the cache.

This has been useful to me a number of times, for example, when I needed to update a feed for submission to iTunes.

Comment: Decent solution - but I wish there was a way to code something to get around this.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
 function do_not_cache_feeds(&$feed) {
   $feed->enable_cache(false);
 }

 add_action( 'wp_feed_options', 'do_not_cache_feeds' );
```

Comment: Yep, this would kill caching on `fetch_feed()` so must note - **never use such code in production environment**, this can be crazy performance killer and I had encounter crappy plugin in the past that killed caching and pretty much destroyed site's load speed.

Comment: Didn't do what what I was looking for, but I think my question was just unclear. See my clarification above - I'm not trying to *fetch* a feed, I'm trying to *generate* a custom feed.

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I was looking for. I was having problems with my feed not refreshing while I was trying to add custom post types to it...

Answer (score -2):

I have been all day find solution to deal with the feed cache as it is not easy to be cleared while I need it as a developer. Finally I got solution by implementing a script that I found here.

I put the script in wordpress root folder so each time I make an update to the source feed I just only do clearing the rss cache by run the script like this:

```
http://mywordpress.com/reset_wp_rss.php
```

This script will eliminate the current cached feed so later it will force wordpress to get the new updated feed to show up.

Comment: What is the code?